# How to define a permission to save a file on Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, postgresql

I am trying to install postgreSQL

I open terminal and type the

```
gedit  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

then in Gedit I enter this line

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ zesty-pgdg main
```

The when I try to save the file red colored text appears saying:

> Could not save the file “/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list”.
>   you do not have the permission necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Downvoting due to apparent lack of research. [How to install postgresql](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) properly is clearly documented.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify this file as root. From the terminal, type

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

Then you can modify inside gedit and save it as you tried before

The `sudo` command means that you will run the command as root and it will ask you for your password

Comment: thanks solve that problem further you tell me how to install postgresql

Comment: Don't use GUI applications with `sudo` (without additional parameters) this will change some file's permissions in the user's home directory, that will cause errors in the future. Use: `sudo -H`, or `sudo -i`, or `gksu` (`gksudo`). The best approach is to learn to work with some terminal based editor as `nano` - `sudo nano /path/to/file` is correct. To recover from previous wrong usage: `sudo chown $USER:USER $HOME`.

Comment: @kashif `sudo apt-get install postgresql`

Comment: Installation completely continued but a error fond that